# Issues drawing ray cast as line on click

Tags: opengl, opengl-3

I've been working on converting screen to world coordinate for the last week or so (previous but unrelated question: [Depth Component of Converting from Window -> World Coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23486230/depth-component-of-converting-from-window-world-coordinates)).

I've made a lot of progress since that post in simplifying my code but now I am taking the ray cast approach for object selection, and more specifically visualizing the ray by drawing a line first (which is getting drawn but not with the correct coordinates).

[image: visualizing ray casting]

(these 4 lines show what happens when clicking on each corner of the square + the camera has been rotated to view the lines better).

**The code:**

**Vertex shader:**

```
#version 330

layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec4 rcolor;

smooth out vec4 theColor;

uniform vec4 color;
uniform mat4 pv;

void main() {
  gl_Position = pv * position;
  theColor = color;
}
```

**^ where pv is the combination of the projection matrix & view matrix. Relevant code from Camera class:**

```
Camera::Camera()
{
  camPos = glm::vec3(0.0f, 5.0f, 1.0f);
  camLook = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

  fovy = 90.0f;
  aspect = 1.0f;
  near = 0.1f;
  far = 100.0f;
}

glm::mat4 Camera::projectionMatrix()
{
  return glm::perspective(fovy, aspect, near, far);
}

glm::mat4 Camera::viewMatrix()
{
  return glm::lookAt(
    camPos,
    camLook,
    glm::vec3(0, 1, 0)
  );
}

glm::mat4 Camera::projectionViewMatrix()
{
  return projectionMatrix() * viewMatrix();
}
```

**On click I initialize a Ray object:**

```
void initializeRay(int x, int y)
{
  Ray rayObj(
    camera.getWorldNear(x, y),
    camera.getWorldFar(x, y)
  );
  rays.push_back(rayObj);
}
```

**(relevant functions from the Camera class) - probably where the issue is**

```
glm::vec3 Camera::getWorldNear(int x, int y)
{
  GLint viewport[4];
  glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);

  glm::vec3 worldNear = glm::unProject(
    glm::vec3(x, viewport[3] - y, near),
    viewMatrix(),
    projectionMatrix(),
    glm::vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, viewport[2], viewport[3])
  );

  printf("near: (%f, %f, %f)\n", worldNear.x, worldNear.y, worldNear.z);

  return worldNear;
}

glm::vec3 Camera::getWorldFar(int x, int y)
{
  GLint viewport[4];
  glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);

  glm::vec3 worldFar = glm::unProject(
    glm::vec3(x, viewport[3] - y, far),
    viewMatrix(),
    projectionMatrix(),
    glm::vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, viewport[2], viewport[3])
  );

  printf("far: (%f, %f, %f)\n", worldFar.x, worldFar.y, worldFar.z);

  return worldFar;
}
```

**and construct the object....**

```
Ray::Ray(glm::vec3 worldNear, glm::vec3 worldFar)
{
  float temp[] = {
    worldNear.x, worldNear.y, worldNear.z,
    worldFar.x, worldFar.y, worldFar.z,
  };

  vertexData.resize(6);
  for (x = 0; x < 6; x++)
    vertexData[x] = temp[x];

  glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexData.size() * sizeof(float), &vertexData[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

**And each time the display function is called, all rays are drawn:**

```
void drawRays()
{
  for (int x = 0; x < rays.size(); x++) {
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, rays[x].vbo);

    glVertexAttribPointer(
      0,
      2,
      GL_FLOAT,
      GL_FALSE,
      0,
      (void*)0
    );

    glUniform4f(colorUniform, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 2);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
  }
}
```

My initial thought was that I was using the `glm::unProject` function in the wrong way, however I also tried changing the start and end position of the ray to the `camPos` & `camLook` (camera position & camera look at position) without any luck (again the rays seemed to all be clustered at the top of the square).

**Edit:**

I also made a function to get the direction of the ray, but it remains unused in my code at the moment:

```
glm::vec3 Camera::getRay(int x, int y)
{
  glm::vec3 worldNear = glm::unProject(
    glm::vec3(x, screenHeight - y, near),
    viewMatrix(),
    projectionMatrix(),
    glm::vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, screenWidth, screenHeight)
  );

  glm::vec3 worldFar = glm::unProject(
    glm::vec3(x, screenHeight - y, far),
    viewMatrix(),
    projectionMatrix(),
    glm::vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, screenWidth, screenHeight)
  );

  glm::vec3 direction = worldFar - worldNear;
  direction - glm::normalize(direction);

  printf("(%f, %f, %f)\n", direction.x, direction.y, direction.z);
  return direction;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To be absolutely clear, where are these rays you are visualizing supposed to originate? I imagine you are clicking some arbitrary location in *window-space* and want the ray to start there?

`glm::UnProject (...)` wants coordinates in *window-space*, but you are actually supplying ***near*** and ***far*** defined in *view-space* right now. It is easy to forget that transformation into *window-space* is defined by your viewport (NDC<sub>x,y</sub> **->** Win<sub>x,y</sub>) ***and*** also depth range (NDC<sub>z</sub> **->** Win<sub>z</sub>).

### Your near and far plane positions go through multiple transformations:

#### It starts out:

`near` = **0.1** and `far` = **100.0** (view-space)

#### After projection and perspective division:

`near` = **-1.0** and `far` = **1.0** (NDC space)

#### Finally, after viewport transformation<sup>*</sup>:

`near` = **0.0** and `far` = **1.0** (window-space)

<sup>*The ***default*** depth range GL uses is [**0.0**, **1.0**]</sup>.

This means that after projection and viewport transformation, the near plane is **0.0** and the far plane is **1.0**.

Comment: Thus, your end point is ***way*** beyond the range of clipped coordinates, and your start point is actually 10% of the way to the far plane. I do not know if this is your only problem, but it is a pretty significant one.